# Noise reduction in speech recognition for videos

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am looking for automatic speech recognition in videos. I am not looking for an accurate "transcription" but instead for a system which can recognize some specific key words with decent accuracy.

The problem I seem to face is with non-speech videos (regular TV recordings for instance) where there is some background noise (crowd cheering, claps etc) or music. Are there any known approaches I should consider to may be "extract" human voice and then pass it to a speech recognizer like sphinx? I understand that this could be a very open-problem but I am NOT looking for a super high-accuracy here, at least to start with.
I have seen some commercial systems do a decent job at this. I am looking for places I should start looking at.

I am new to this area - so any help would be great.